# Update payment descriptor with Stripe payment system

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe payment system with laravel.
I have two type user

1) Client

2) Advisor

The client gives payment to the advisor.

When an advisor has a meeting I issue a payment to their bank account through stripe. The advisor can see the payment in their bank account and it right now says Stripe. It should say your custome website name.

Please, Give me advise. How can I change?

Comment: When [create charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_charge) include `description` and/or `statement_descriptor` to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can direct add statement_descriptor in Stripe's dashboard.

Follow the step : [Stripe Connect with manual payouts](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205811328-Adding-a-statement-descriptor-in-Stripe)

Answer (score 1):

> When an advisor has a meeting I issue a payment to their bank account through stripe.

If by this you mean that you are using [Stripe Connect with manual payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts), then you can pass a `statement_descriptor` parameter to the [API call](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_payout-statement_descriptor).